# При масштабировании элемента, текст внутри него не на долго меняется

Tags: html, css, transform, transition, scale

Есть элемент, при наведении на него он должен увеличится в размере (сделано это при помощи transform: scale(1.1)). Во время увеличения элемента, текст внутри него не на долго изменяется (как будто на секунду размер шрифта становится меньше, а потом опять возвращается). Можно ли это как-то исправить?...

**Вот код**: https://codepen.io/talisman4ik123/pen/rNwvvpr

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 600px;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.card__content {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.card__text {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 140%;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.card__title {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <svg class="card__svg" width="60" height="60" viewBox="0 0 60 60" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M2 2H3H15H15.4055L15.6965 2.28246L32.4754 18.5698C32.5204 18.4768 32.5698 18.3853 32.6241 18.2961C33.0882 17.5334 33.8743 17 35 17C35.7101 17 36.3203 17.2134 36.8006 17.6181C37.2639 18.0084 37.5338 18.5153 37.6959 18.9882C38.0007 19.877 38.0003 20.8912 38 21.4541V21.4541L38 21.5V35.5H52.5V21.5L52.5 21.4541V21.4541C52.4997 20.8912 52.4993 19.877 52.8041 18.9882C52.9662 18.5153 53.2361 18.0084 53.6994 17.6181C54.1797 17.2134 54.7899 17 55.5 17C56.2101 17 56.8203 17.2134 57.3006 17.6181C57.7639 18.0084 58.0338 18.5153 58.1959 18.9882C58.5007 19.877 58.5003 20.8912 58.5 21.4541V21.4541L58.5 21.5V57V58H57.5H53.5H37H33H32.5858L32.2929 57.7071L2.29289 27.7071L2 27.4142V27V25V6.5V3V2ZM52.5 37.5H38V39.5H52.5V37.5ZM52.5 41.5H38V45H52.5V41.5ZM52.5 47H38V50.5H52.5V47ZM52.5 52.5H38V56H52.5V52.5ZM56.5 56V22.5H54.5V36.5V40.5V46V51.5V56H56.5ZM56.4685 20.5C56.442 20.194 56.3933 19.8972 56.3041 19.6368C56.2162 19.3805 56.1111 19.2312 56.0119 19.1475C55.9297 19.0783 55.7899 19 55.5 19C55.2101 19 55.0703 19.0783 54.9881 19.1475C54.8889 19.2312 54.7838 19.3805 54.6959 19.6368C54.6067 19.8972 54.558 20.194 54.5315 20.5H56.4685ZM36 56V51.5V46V40.5V36.5V22.5H34V26V36.5V56H36ZM32 54.5858L4 26.5858V26H10.5V29V30H11.5H18V32.5V33.5H19H25.5V36.5V37.5H26.5H32V54.5858ZM32 35.5V26.4216L27.5 22.0341V32.5V35.5H32ZM25.5 20.0841L20 14.7216V29V31.5H25.5V20.0841ZM18 12.7716L12.5932 7.5H12.5V25V28H18V12.7716ZM10.5 7.5V24H4V7.5H10.5ZM4 5.5H11.5H13H13.4068L13.6981 5.784L19.6981 11.634L27.1981 18.9465L32 23.6284V21.5V21.4899V21.4895C32 21.3245 32 21.1232 32.0065 20.9019L14.5945 4H4V5.5ZM34.0315 20.5H35.9685C35.942 20.194 35.8933 19.8972 35.8041 19.6368C35.7162 19.3805 35.6111 19.2312 35.5119 19.1475C35.4297 19.0783 35.2899 19 35 19C34.7733 19 34.6428 19.0485 34.5647 19.0936C34.4848 19.1398 34.4073 19.213 34.3326 19.3358C34.1738 19.5968 34.0758 20.0005 34.0315 20.5ZM17 36.5C17 35.9477 17.4477 35.5 18 35.5H23H24V36.5V39.5H29H30V40.5V44C30 44.5523 29.5523 45 29 45C28.4477 45 28 44.5523 28 44V41.5H23H22V40.5V37.5H18C17.4477 37.5 17 37.0523 17 36.5ZM15 34C15.263 34 15.521 33.893 15.7069 33.707C15.8929 33.521 16 33.263 16 33C16 32.736 15.893 32.479 15.7069 32.293C15.521 32.106 15.263 32 15 32C14.737 32 14.479 32.106 14.293 32.293C14.107 32.479 14 32.736 14 33C14 33.263 14.1069 33.521 14.293 33.707C14.479 33.893 14.737 34 15 34ZM29.7069 48.707C29.521 48.893 29.263 49 29 49C28.737 49 28.479 48.893 28.293 48.707C28.1069 48.521 28 48.263 28 48C28 47.736 28.107 47.479 28.293 47.293C28.479 47.106 28.737 47 29 47C29.263 47 29.521 47.106 29.7069 47.293C29.893 47.479 30 47.736 30 48C30 48.263 29.8929 48.521 29.7069 48.707Z" fill="#202020"/>
          </svg>
      <div class="card__content">
        <h5 class="card__title">Любые варианты отделки</h5>
        <p class="card__text"> Любые материалы отделки готовых лестниц — от дерева<br> и камня до кованых элементов и стекла.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Попробуй добавить `will-change: transform;` для `.card`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!